# Removing multiple object from array

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, removechild

I place the MC in an array and would like to remove it later on from an index maybe till the end.

```
//Removeing MC from stage, from an index till the end
LISTmc.removeChild(listArray[clickedIndex+1]);

//Removing MC starting from an index till the end
listArray.splice(clickedIndex+1);
```

Is the way to remove the MC from the stage same with removing it from array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that for the MovieClips in the array you remove you also want to remove those from the stage?

```
for (var i:int = clickedIndex+1; i < listArray.length;i++)
{
  //if this is on timeline leave as is otherwise you need to reference stage
  removeChild(listArray[i]);

  //if the movieclips are in various movieclips then you can do:
  // var parent:DisplayObject = (listArray[i]).parent;
  // parent.removeChild(listArray[i]);

}

listArray = listArray.slice(0,clickedIndex);//returns a new array from start index to end index
```